# What do you get when you mix a crossword and a sudoku?

Tags: sudoku, crosswords

For this CrosSudoku puzzle you must completely solve the sudoku grid below. To start the sudoku you must first figure out the crossword clues to get the starting numbers.

**Clue notation:**

- x and y are used to indicate an unknown number
- variable in single quotes are concatenated (sometimes will have a comma in the quotes to clarify seperated values)
- some clues have parts that are to figure specific number (x or y) that will help lead to the answer. The part of the clue that is specific for the answer will be pointed to by an arrow
- Example: the clue   x+2=7 --> 'xx, 4'   would lead to answer 554

Good Luck!

> [image: CrosSudoku]
>
> ```
> ACROSS: 
>  1. A square and a 4th power 
>  2. Don't be immature 
>  3. A square and a 4th power 
>  5. A square and a team 
>  6. y=2x --> 'xy'=y^2 
>  7. 3/4 
>  8. The answer to ... 
>  10. '1/4, Nintendo' 
>  11. Why was 6 afraid? 
>  12. 'x^2, (x+1)^2' 
>  13. x+y=z --> 'x,y,z' 
>  14. 'x,y'= 1/2 -x --> 'x,y' 
>  15. 3 ACROSS 
>  16. 'x,x+1' 
>  18. What's 9+10? 
>  
> DOWN: 
>  4. Base__ 
>  6. 'x,x+2,x+1' 
>  7. A tiny bit over 3/4 
>  8. 8x3x7(10 ACROSS +315) 
>  9. '2 ACROSS, 2' flipped 
>  11. '3/x, x' 
>  13. x^x upside down 
>  15. twice lucky 
>  17. Back to the beginning
> ```

Comment: Is 13 across correct? How can there be 'x,y,x' in one line? This would be the same number twice. Or am I misinterpreting your notation?

Comment: Unless 18A is cryptic it seems to conflict with 11A

Comment: @formica Some how I had overlooked that typo and the error 11D when copying from my notes. Luckily Jonathan was still able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer might be:

> 5 3 2 | 8 1 7 | 6 9 4
>  1 6 7 | 2 9 4 | 8 5 3
>  8 4 9 | 5 3 6 | 2 1 7
>  ---------------------
>  9 8 6 | 7 5 3 | 1 4 2
>  3 2 5 | 6 4 1 | 7 8 9
>  4 7 1 | 9 8 2 | 5 3 6
>  ---------------------
>  7 1 8 | 3 2 9 | 4 6 5
>  2 9 4 | 1 6 5 | 3 7 8
>  6 5 3 | 4 7 8 | 9 2 1

Assuming (1) that 13A should read "x+y=z --> 'x,y,z'" and (2) that 11D should read "'3/x, x'".

Although then I don't know how 18A and 17D make sense.

The answers are then:

> ACROSS:
>   1. A square and a 4th power = 81
>   2. Don't be immature = 69
>   3. A square and a 4th power = 16
>   5. A square and a team = 49
>   6. y=2x --> 'xy'=y^2 = 36
>   7. 3/4 = .75
>   8. The answer to ...  = 42
>   10. '1/4, Nintendo' = .25,64
>   11. Why was 6 afraid? = because 7 ate 9 = 789
>   12. 'x^2, (x+1)^2' = 25,36
>   13. x+y=z --> 'x,y,z' = 7,1,8
>   14. 'x,y'= 1/2 -x --> 'x,y' = 4,6 (because 46 = 50 - 4)
>   15. 3 ACROSS = 16
>   16. 'x,x+1' =7,8
>   18. What's 9+10? = 21 ???
>
>
>   DOWN:
>   4. Base__ = 64 (one of the more commonly used bases)
>   6. 'x,x+2,x+1' = 3,5,4
>   7. A tiny bit over 3/4 = .76
>   8. 8x3x7(10 ACROSS +315) = 8x3x7x(2564+315) = 483672
>   9. '2 ACROSS, 2' flipped = 96,2
>   11. '3/x, x' = .75,4
>   13. x^x upside down  3^3 = 27 -> 72
>   15. twice lucky = 2x7 = 14
>   17. Back to the beginning = 81 (answer to 1A - thanks @Chris)

Comment: I got the same thing. 17D I think just means the beginning of the list of clues, so 1A. No idea why 18A is what it is though.

Comment: Maybe for 18A rot13(pbzovar gur Ebzna ahzoref VK naq K gb KKV)

Comment: @formica that'd work

Comment: @Chris  18A was actual a reference to a meme/vine if you google Whats 9 + 10? it is one of the first things to come up if you are still curious. That is a cool coincidence about the roman numeral thing though.