# Didn't you ask me for a crossword?

Tags: logical-deduction, word, grid-deduction, sudoku, crosswords

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #forty-seven: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

---

Here's that crossword you asked for... Sorry, what's that - you didn't ask me for a crossword??

> **TASK: Solve the puzzle (COMPLETELY) to find a concealed nine-letter word which tells you something that this puzzle is *not*...**

[image]

> **Across**
> A) Shakespearean King
> D) "Let it be so"
> E) Organ of hearing
> G) ____ Nordegren, model and ex-wife of Tiger Woods
> I) Creditor's legal right over a debtor's property
> K) UK Protestant Christian denomination formed in nineteen-seventy-two (inits)
> M) Muslim ruler
> N) Nostril
>
> **Down**
> A) Queue
> B) Precipitation
> C) French indefinite article
> F) Highest point
> H) Alternative name for ribosomal protein SA
> I) Northern English dialect word: 'be taught'
> J) Major river in Africa
> L) Animation still

Comment: This should be fairly quick to solve but has taken DAYS to put together in a workable way without *too many* obscure words. I've never seen it attempted **in full** before on PSE, only *partially* on a couple of occasions... It really has just been a case of "Is this possible? Let's try and see!"

Comment: Very nice puzzle! This must have taken forever to find a grid that works for both, and to still be solvable as well! Incredibly impressive, and a very fun solve :)

Comment: Now that the puzzle has been solved, here are a couple of the posts I was referring to in my comment above (in case anyone is interested): [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58194) by Alconja is one of my PSE faves, but the crossword is not self-contained in the 9x9 grid, and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74038) by gabbo1092 is similar in idea, but does not produce a symmetrical crossword. Applying both of these additional limitations was HARD, especially when further constraining it by requiring a specific letter set for the hidden word! :)

Comment: Nitpick (trying not to spoil anything):  Clue C would be better clued as "French feminine article" or something like that.  The first natural number is the form with one letter less;  the word you've used is not used for counting in French.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That's fair. I'd used the wording as I felt it (loosely) fitted with the theme. But I've changed it now in line with your suggestion, in the name of accuracy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This puzzle is certainly not

> **NUMERICAL**!

---

Solving the crossword:

> [image]

The clues:

> **Across**
>  A) Shakespearean King - **[LEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Lear)**
>  D) "Let it be so" - **AMEN**
>  E) Organ of hearing - **EAR**
>  G) ____ Nordegren, model and ex-wife of Tiger Woods - **[ELIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elin_Nordegren)**
>  I) Creditor's legal right over a debtor's property - **[LIEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lien)**
>  K) UK Protestant Christian denomination formed in nineteen-seventy-two (inits) - **[URC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Reformed_Church)**
>  M) Muslim ruler - **[EMIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emir)**
>  N) Nostril - **[NARE](https://www.yourdictionary.com/nare#:%7E:text=Filters,noun)**
>
>  **Down**
>  A) Queue - **LINE**
>  B) Precipitation - **RAIN**
>  C) French indefinite article - **UNE**
>  F) Highest point - **[ACME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme)**
>  H) Alternative name for ribosomal protein SA - **[LAMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosomal_protein_SA)**
>  I) Northern English dialect word: 'be taught' - **[LARN](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/larn)**
>  J) Major river in Africa - **NILE**
>  L) Animation still - **[CEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel)**

Then solving as a 'Wordoku':

(Not posted logical path as it is quite straightforward, but can if needed)

> [image]
>
> Gives us the final answer in the middle box - **NUMERICAL**!!
>
> This is apt, as not only does the sudoku not use any numbers, but even the crossword uses letters instead of numbers too!

Comment: Did you solve the crossword entirely before the Wordoku?

Comment: @bobble, yup, but for a couple of clues I wasn't entirely sure on I did use the sudoku constrictions to help work out what it could be

Comment: Nice work BG :) No need for a detailed solve path on this one IMO - the 2 stages you have here are sufficient. Perfect example of a puzzle that's MUCH quicker to solve than to set!

Comment: Thank you and awesome work! Yeah, there was too many characters on the grid for me to think it needed a full explanation, but that'll probably always be the case with this combo. And absolutely this must have taken a ton of work to make! Hopefully this gets way more upvotes than whatever this gets because it is very much deserved!